# Fetching index of array inside JSON object on javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am trying to fetch the values of the numbers inside an array of a JSON object.

Here is how the JSON object looks like

```
 {
    "item[]": [
            "1",
            "2",
            "3",
            "4",
            "5",
            "6",
            "8",
            "7",
            "9",
            "10",
            "11",
            "12"
    ]
}
```

This object comes from a jquery serialize. I have tried,

```
var obj = req.body;
obj.length //Returns undefined

obj.item ///Return undefined

obj.item[] //Program crashes
```

I need to access the value so I can make it look something like:

```
Index 1 = 1
Index 2 = 2
Index 3 = 3 //And so on
```

How can I achieve this through looping in javascript?

Comment: `obj['item[]'].length`

Comment: `var obj = req.body;`  if this code is on node server, then are you doing `app.use(bodyParser.json())` on node?

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. If you *are* dealing with a string, use `JSON.parse` ot parse it, at which point you're not dealing with a string anymore. But given that `obj.length` is undefined, it sounds like you're not dealing with a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use bracket notation `obj['item[]']` instead of dot notation and then you can use `forEach` loop to get each element of array.

```js
var obj = {"item[]":["1","2","3","4","5","6","8","7","9","10","11","12"]}

obj['item[]'].forEach(function(e, i) {
  console.log('Index ' + i + ' = ' + e);
})
```